# Unable to edit Joomla template

Tags: javascript, php, joomla

Am new here and also new to joomla.Will really appreciate if anyone can direct me to the site I can read more about it joomla.Kindly recommend a video site
Thanks in advance

Comment: Check how to ask here. Use google to find such answers.

Comment: you can use joomla.stackexchange.com for your general questions on Joomla.